# Automatically turn bluetooth on or off depending on current network (MBP running Lion)

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth, macos

Is there any way to automatically turn Bluetooth on or off when my MacBook Pro (mid-2010, running Lion) joins specific networks? I typically want Bluetooth off except when I am connected to my home wireless or wired network. It would be really handy if I could configure Bluetooth to turn on whenever I join my home network(s), and likewise, turn it off when I join a non-home network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ControlPlane](https://github.com/dustinrue/ControlPlane) is a supported development based on Marco Polo.

Comment: Developer has stopped working on it, see https://www.controlplaneapp.com/2017/11/03/the-state-of-controlplane/

Answer (score 1):

Once upon a time I was using the free app [Macro Polo](http://www.symonds.id.au/marcopolo/) to do location-aware configuration changes on my MBPro. Sadly, it's not been supported or developed since Snow Leopard. It's still available to try though and it might work well enough on Snow Leopard or Lion to meet your needs. Worth a shot, costs you nothing but time really.

[Locations 3](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locations-3/id437317622?mt=12&ls=1) in the MAS purports to do all of the same things as Marco Polo. Included in the list of things it can change is enabling and disabling your BlueTooth radio. I haven't used it though so I can't speak to how well it works. If it's half as good as Marco Polo, it should be pretty useful.