# macOS 10.14: switch Bluetooth on/off based on location

Tags: bluetooth, automation

I use the same laptop in 2 locations. In one location I use bluetooth to operate the mouse and keyboard, whereas in the other I don't use bluetooth at all.

Apart from the seemingly defunct ControlPlane and Macro Polo there any way to automatically switch bluetooth on/off based on my location on macos 10.14 (i.e. when I am connected to a specific Wifi), i.e. via the Automator or scripting?

PS: I'm aware that the question has been asked before ([Automatically turn bluetooth on or off depending on current network (MBP running Lion)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33844/automatically-turn-bluetooth-on-or-off-depending-on-current-network-mbp-running)). But the URL in the accepted answer is broken and ControlPlane has numerous issue with macOS Sierra and later, as well as in the developers own words "This project is in need of assistance.". So IMO the accepted answer is no longer a viable solution for macOS. The other answer using Macro Polo has not been supported since Snow Leopard, and ControlPlane is a direct port of it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It would help us if you provided additional info, such as the types of devices, OS, etc.  Also let us know what you've already done to solve the problem yourself.  Please see [ask] for how to ask good questions that have a better chance at being answered.

Comment: To the Close voters... While it may be a possible duplicate, the URL in the accepted answer is broken and ControlPlane has numerous issue with macOS Sierra and later, as well as in the developers own words "This project is in need of assistance.". So IMO the accepted answer is no longer a viable solution for macOS. The other answer using Macro Polo has not been supported since Snow Leopard, and ControlPlane is a direct port of it. I'd leave this question open for answers pointing to working apps that are currently actively being developed.

Comment: @user3439894 Good explanation, it's probably easier to avoid votes to close if you edit things like this directly into the question.

Comment: @nohillside, sounds good and will do the next time, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is just one of the many things that you can do with [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) which is $36 but which enables you to do at least 1,000 different things with your Mac. You can have triggers for sleep/wake, or when you are on a certain Wi-Fi network, or at specific times of day, etc.

Those triggers can then run AppleScript events, or execute keyboard commands, or mouse commands, or shell scripts, or a large suite of actions built-in to Keyboard Maestro.

You can [download it here for free](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/action/download?km-kmi-7-b3) and try it for ~30 days.

The developer is very responsive to emails, as well as hosting an active [discussion forum](https://forum.keyboardmaestro.com/) where the developer is active, but so are many Keyboard Maestro users (including me).

Answer (score 0):

I use a program named [EventScripts](https://www.mousedown.net/software/EventScripts.html) which among the *events* it monitors, there are these *events* that may apply to your question, **External IP address changed**, **Wireless network changed** and or **Location updated**. It uses **AppleScript** *scripts* to preform the *action(s)* you want to have happen when a given *event* is triggered.

It is a paid app, $3.99 USD, but does have a demo version you can download to test with before purchasing.

- [Mac App Store Preview (US)](https://apps.apple.com/app/eventscripts/id525319418?mt=12)
- [Download for Demo](https://www.mousedown.net/software/Downloads.html)

---

<sup>Note: Other then being a paid user of this app, I have no affiliation with its developer.</sup>